# Number of ways of occupying houses

Tags: combinatorics, permutations

There are $65$ houses in a street numbered $0-64$ and the first and last houses are occupied. The remaining $63$ houses have to be occupied. If $a$-numbered and $b$-numbered houses are occupied then the person can only occupy $\frac{a+b}{2}$th house where $a$ and $b$ are consecutive occupied houses. What is the number of ways in which all houses can be occupied?

I tried considering cases but I can't see any obvious pattern. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Not following.  Who is "the person"?   What does "can occupy" mean?  What happens if $a+b$ is odd?

Comment: @lulu $a+b$ is never odd...

Comment: Please edit to include your efforts and to clarify the problem.  Perhaps it would help if you provided examples of "good" configurations and "bad" ones, to illustrate whatever rules you want followed.

Comment: @Momo  Why is $a+b$ never odd?  Is that a rule the OP forgot to mention?

Comment: @lulu edited the question

Comment: I don't see where you included any efforts, nor where you clarified the problem in any way.

Comment: You can build a binary tree. The first house to be occupied is $32$ (one choice), then in the next step you have two choices: $16$ and $48$ and so on. Then the number of ways in which the house can be occupied is the number of ways the binary tree can be traversed.

Comment: @lulu because $64=2^6$

Comment: @Momo you seem to have some idea of what the question is asking, I have none.

Comment: Perhaps it would help if you solved the problem for $4$ houses, instead of $64$.  Or for $8$.  Surely, those cases are trivial, no?

Comment: It seems to me that *a* and *b* can be any numbers. But if they are such that a subsequent "occupation" is impossible, we fail. The task is to **choose** $a's $ and $b's$ so that all houses get occupied.

Comment: @lulu Think about a stick of size 64. At the first step, we cut it in half, then we continue to cut each of the remaining pieces in half until we get pieces of size 1. Does it make sense?

Comment: @Momo  Ah, so the question concerns the *order* in which the houses are filled.  That makes sense, thank you.

Comment: So after you build the complete binary tree, you are left with the number of ways this binary tree can be traversed, for which somebody has already found a recursive formula: [Number Of Ways To Traverse a Binary Tree](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33071800/number-of-ways-to-traverse-a-binary-tree). Since your binary tree is complete, I think you can get a closed-form formula for it.

Answer (score 1):

To summarize what I wrote in the comments:

Let $S_{2^n}$ be the number of ways people can move in $2^n+1$ houses (numbered $0,1,2,\ldots 2^n$). We use divide and conquer to devise a recurrence:

Obviously $S_{2^1}=1$

For the general case, the first person has to move in the middle, after which each solution to occupy the houses can be constructed by combining a solution for the left side with a solution for the right side (${S_{2^{n-1}}^2}$ ways), and interleaving moves in the left and right halves, which can be done in
${2^n-2\choose 2^{n-1}-1}$ ways.

Putting it all together:

$$S_{2^n}={2^n-2\choose 2^{n-1}-1}S_{2^{n-1}}^2$$

which for 65 houses gives:

$
2606654998899867556195703676289609067340669424836280320000000000
$